# How can I get Scanner.nextInt() to get the next int?

Tags: java, file-io

Alright, I have never had this issue before, and I find it really strange. I'm trying to read input from a file for this patient triage program. The first three calls to those methods work, however when I call fileRead.nextInt() it blows up and gives me an InputMismatchException. The lines I am reading go a little like this: http://gyazo.com/74c0a9381479a12bb4804d714901b41c and I am quite sure the delimiters I am using are correct. It doesn't matter if I remove the cast to char and try to do it as int, it just won't work. Why? I've done a program similar to this one and fileRead.next() three times (to get the three tokens on the line) worked perfectly.

```
void loadPatientData() throws FileNotFoundException
 {
    linkHeads();
    Patient person = null;
    Scanner fileRead = makeAFile(patient);
    fileRead.useDelimiter(";|\n");

    while (fileRead.hasNext())
    {
        //person = new Patient(fileRead.next(), fileRead.nextBoolean(), fileRead.nextBoolean(), (char)fileRead.nextInt());
        String name = fileRead.next();
        boolean bob = fileRead.nextBoolean();
        boolean joe = fileRead.nextBoolean();
        int queue = fileRead.nextInt(); //hell breaks loose
        //addPatientData(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to read all the values as strings with fileRead.next() and then convert them into formats you need?

Comment: At least for diagnostic purposes, try @Bfcm's suggestion and see if it still throws an exception.

Comment: use hasNextInt() for checking if the next token is an int or not, before calling nextInt().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you're on windows and your text file displays correctly in notepad.exe, I'm going to assume that your file actually uses `\r\n` as newline, instead of just `\n`, which would explain the exception at `nextInt()`.

Example:

```
static void loadPatientData()  {
    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner("John Doe;true;true;0\r\nJane Roe;false;true;2\r\n");
    fileRead.useDelimiter(";|\r\n"); // vs.:
//  fileRead.useDelimiter(";|\n");

    while (fileRead.hasNext()) {
        String name = fileRead.next();
        boolean bob = fileRead.nextBoolean();
        boolean joe = fileRead.nextBoolean();
        int queue = fileRead.nextInt(); //hell breaks loose
    }
}
```

To cover all cases of newlines you just might want to use `";|\r\n|\n"` as your delimiter.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why it works for the first three lines (which goes through two of the `\n` without incident).

Comment: @edwga I believe "The first three calls to those methods work" is referring to the three `next[Boolean]()` calls before `nextInt()`, successfully retrieving the first 3 tokens of the first line, not referring to the first 3 lines. After all, the `loadPatientData()` method is only supposed to be called once, anyway.

Comment: Yes, in the other program I had, simply using fileRead.useDelimiter(";|\n"); worked perfectly fine. Maybe it is because something other than next() is being called, although I am not positive. But thank you, this fixed the error perfectly.